# SQL ORDER BY by sibling value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 columns they names are `id` and `sibling_id` and types are `uniqueidentifier` I would like to ORDER BY `id` via `sibling_id` programmatically.  My data structure as below and thus values can be change.

```
id                                      sibling_id
------------------------------------    ------------------------------------
4146831B-79FA-6EB4-981B-FF00002477F7    78068B1B-79FA-6EB4-981B-FF00002477F7
53058B1B-79FA-6EB4-981B-FF00002477F7    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
5B058B1B-79FA-6EB4-981B-FF00002477F7    30718C1B-79FA-6EB4-981B-FF00002477F7
78068B1B-79FA-6EB4-981B-FF00002477F7    5B058B1B-79FA-6EB4-981B-FF00002477F7
80068B1B-79FA-6EB4-981B-FF00002477F7    4146831B-79FA-6EB4-981B-FF00002477F7
30718C1B-79FA-6EB4-981B-FF00002477F7    53058B1B-79FA-6EB4-981B-FF00002477F7
```

Expected ORDER BY as below

```
Order   id                                      sibling_id
------  ------------------------------------    ------------------------------------
1       53058B1B-79FA-6EB4-981B-FF00002477F7    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
2       30718C1B-79FA-6EB4-981B-FF00002477F7    53058B1B-79FA-6EB4-981B-FF00002477F7
3       5B058B1B-79FA-6EB4-981B-FF00002477F7    30718C1B-79FA-6EB4-981B-FF00002477F7
4       78068B1B-79FA-6EB4-981B-FF00002477F7    5B058B1B-79FA-6EB4-981B-FF00002477F7
5       4146831B-79FA-6EB4-981B-FF00002477F7    78068B1B-79FA-6EB4-981B-FF00002477F7
6       80068B1B-79FA-6EB4-981B-FF00002477F7    4146831B-79FA-6EB4-981B-FF00002477F7
```

Comment: put `order by sibling_id`at the end of your query ?

Comment: I don't understand neither output sorting nor requirements

Comment: Your expected order does not makes sense to me. Can you please clarify ?

Comment: Oh, so that is a tree... Why "sibling" then?

Comment: @GuidoG what did you understand? What is your problem? If it can order by sibling_id I can do that. I would like to order id values via sibling values.

Comment: my problem, and also others have this problem as you can see in the comments, is that we do not  understand how exact you got to the ordering in your expected order by. You should explain better what you need

Comment: @IvanStarostin I am working on commercial database. Its developer did not use classic id approach. They are objects of html page. I am getting all parts of html but I need to order them first of response.

Comment: @GuidoG my main language is not English. I try to write clean. But I think if you examine question little careful I think you understand What I need.

Comment: it is all written clean and in good english, all that is missing is the explanation how you got to your expected result

Comment: @GuidoG thank you very much I will be more careful next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [**recursive CTE**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) to get the ordering:

```
;WITH TraverseTree AS (
   -- Anchor query: get root node
   SELECT 1 as [order], id, sibling_id   
   FROM mytable AS t
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM mytable AS x
                     WHERE x.id = t.sibling_id)

   UNION ALL

   -- Recursive query: get node of next level
   SELECT  t2.[order] + 1 AS [order], t1.id, t1.sibling_id  
   FROM mytable AS t1
   JOIN TraverseTree AS t2 ON t1.sibling_id = t2.id
)
SELECT *
FROM TraverseTree
ORDER BY [order]
```

The `CTE` starts by selecting the root node, i.e. the record having no parent. Based on the sample data provided this record is:

```
53058B1B-79FA-6EB4-981B-FF00002477F7    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

Then the recursive query is repeatedly executed until no records are returned by it. Upon its first execution the child record of the previous record is selected:

```
30718C1B-79FA-6EB4-981B-FF00002477F7    53058B1B-79FA-6EB4-981B-FF00002477F7
```

and so on, until the whole of the tree has been traversed.

**Note:** The field name `sibling_id` is a bit misleading. It should be called `father_id` in my opinion.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fbc27/6)

Comment: Thank you very much that is good sample but I have huge SELECT query. I wrote here only two colmuns. Is there any way to use this approach in classic ORDER BY line of t-sql?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to get the depth of a node (named `[order]` in the query above) using a standard sql query. You can edit the query posted in order to add any other columns that you like.

Comment: OK thank you very much again. I have used two CTE with your suggestion and it is working like a charm.